# Initializer-list on 3 levels

Tags: c++, class, c++11, initialization, stdvector

How do I properly and easily initialize an instance of a `class` that contains a `std::vector` of some other class that in itself contains some data.

I understand that it is really hard to explain it in words, so I will instead write a piece of code that does not work, but it captures my intention.

```
#include <vector>

struct Point
{
   float x, y;
};

struct Triangle
{
   Point points[3];
};

struct Geometry
{
   std::vector<Triangle> triangles;
};

int main()
{
   Geometry instance
   {
     {{0,0}, {6, 0}, {3, 3}},
     {{5,2}, {6, 6}, {7, 3}}
   };
   return 0;
}
```

This code does not work. Clang returns an error -

```
excess elements in struct initializer
```

I can not figure out why it is giving me this error.

I imagine that I can initialize

- the *`std::vector` of `Triangle`s*,
- then the array of `Point`s,
- then the two `float`s within each `Point` object.

How would I go about properly initializing an instance of `Geometry` class with some values **without writing too much code using the initializer brackets**?

If you have alternatives, then I am open to considering them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need 2 pairs of additional braces for this to work:

```
Geometry instance
{{
  {{{0,0}, {6, 0}, {3, 3}}},
  {{{5,2}, {6, 6}, {7, 3}}}
}};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6Ts77f).

Explanations for all the braces:

```
Geometry instance
{  // for the Geometry object - instance
 {  // for the vector member - triangles  
  {  // for the individual Triangle objects
   {  // for the Point array - points[3]
    {0,0}, {6, 0}, {3, 3}}},  // for the individual Points
  {{{5,2}, {6, 6}, {7, 3}}}
}};
```

While I like using brace-init lists, when you have nesting this deep it might be more readable to spell out the types explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

You can mention the `triangles`'s type and provide a set of extra parentheses, [then it should work](https://godbolt.org/z/EcqPo3)

```
Geometry instance{
   std::vector<Triangle> // explicitly mentioning the type
         {
            { { {0,0}, {6, 0}, {3, 3}} },
            { { {0,0}, {6, 0}, {3, 3}} }
         }
};
```